# Class Instance in YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have a test.yaml file in /opt directory in Ubuntu in which I have my db settings and I get that file in environment.rb  as shown

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
class Settings
raw_config = File.read("/opt/test.yml")
erb_config = ERB.new(raw_config).result
settings = YAML.load(erb_config)[::Rails.env]
 if settings
  settings.each  do |name, value|
  puts "checking array" , name, value
  instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value)
  self.class.class_eval { attr_reader name.intern }
 end
 end
end
```

Now in mongoid.yml file i want to use that class as shown in code

```
development:
 sessions:
  default:
   hosts:
    -Settings.sessions["default"]["hosts"]
  username: ve
  password: "123456"
  database: weather
```

but getting error like this 
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure (Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set ]>):

I am a new guy and stuck there.Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Theory:**

They key is to delete `mongod.lock` file and start mongodb service again. The lock file in Ubuntu is located at `/var/lib/mongod.lock`.

**Details:**

I was getting the same error under Ubuntu, this is what I did:

> vagrant@lucid32:~$ sudo service mongodb restart
>
> restart: Unknown instance:
>
> vagrant@lucid32:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/mongod.lock
>
> vagrant@lucid32:~$ sudo service mongodb start
>
> mongodb start/running, process 2340
>
> vagrant@lucid32:~$ sudo service mongodb restart
>
> mongodb start/running, process 2368